# Jenkins - Unable to send slack notifications using Groovy postbuild plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have installed Jenkins on my local Ubuntu 16.04 system

I am able to send notifications using slack notification plugin

But using Groovy postbuild plugin, I am not able to send notifications.
I have done configuration as 
Jenkins Project - Configure - Post Build Actions, I have added Groovy post build. And added following code
Can anyone please help me resolving this issue.

```
  node {
    try {
        notifyBuild('STARTED')

        stage('Prepare code') {
            echo 'do checkout stuff'
        }

        stage('Testing') {
            echo 'Testing'
            echo 'Testing - publish coverage results'
        }

        stage('Staging') {
            echo 'Deploy Stage'
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            echo 'Deploy - Backend'
            echo 'Deploy - Frontend'
        }

  } catch (e) {
    // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
    currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
    throw e
  } finally {
    // Success or failure, always send notifications
    notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
  }
}

def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
  // build status of null means successful
  buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'

  // Default values
  def colorName = 'RED'
  def colorCode = '#FF0000'
  def subject = "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
  def summary = "${subject} (${env.BUILD_URL})"

  // Override default values based on build status
  if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
    color = 'YELLOW'
    colorCode = '#FFFF00'
  } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESSFUL') {
    color = 'GREEN'
    colorCode = '#00FF00'
  } else {
    color = 'RED'
    colorCode = '#FF0000'
  }

  // Send notifications
  slackSend (color: colorCode, message: summary)
}
```

But it shows me following output

```
 # Console Output
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.node() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@4cf2f064]
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), notify(), wait(), run(), run(), any()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:343)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:380)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Extended Email Publisher is currently disabled in project settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a Jenkins pipeline script as groovy postbuild action which will never work as the two have different syntax and usage (that is why you get the error that `node` method is not found).

What you can do is either create a new `Pipeline` with the code you posted, or do not use the groovy postbuild action, but use `Slack Notifications` postbuild action instead.